pdf of $X\diamond Y$.
Let $X, Y$ be random variables.
Let $\diamond : \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous binary operation (think $+$ or $\times$).
I am interested in the pdf of $Z_\diamond := X\diamond Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ need not be independent.
I'll use the notation $p_X(x), p_Y(x), p_{Z_\diamond}(x)$ for the pdfs of $X, Y, Z_\diamond$, and $p_{(X,Y)}(x,y)$ for the (joint) pdf of $(X,Y)$.
I (naively) hope that it is the case that
$$\tag{1}
p_{Z_\diamond}(x) = \iint_{\diamond^{-1}(z)}p_{(X,Y)}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y,
$$
where $\diamond^{-1}(z) = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x\diamond y = z\}$ is the preimage of $z$ under $\diamond$.
This is what makes the most sense to me from the discrete case.
I've typically seen people state that you should compute the pdf of $Z_\diamond$ by differentiating the cdf of $Z_\diamond$.
This would work in the above example, e.g. for binary operations of random variables (defined on $\mathbb{R}$).
I'm mainly interested in arguments that work for random vectors (defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$) though, and the "differentiate the cdf" argument is generally only presented in 1D.

Is Eq. 1 true? If not, is there a generic way to compute the pdf of $Z_\diamond$, for a binary operation $\diamond: \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ that is $n$-dimensional?

Edit: I've seen here that the formula
$$p_X(x) = \mathbb{E}[\delta(X-x)]\tag{2}$$
is a reasonable way to compute the pdf.
Applied to $Z_\diamond$, this gives
$$
p_{Z_\diamond}(z) = \mathbb{E}[\delta(Z_\diamond-z)] = \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\delta(Z_\diamond-z)p_{(X,Y)}(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y=\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\delta(x\diamond y-z)p_{(X,Y)}(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y.
$$
It feels like this should yield my desired formula.
If this is the case, then

Is Eq. 2 well-known (is it in some textbook somewhere), and
does Eq. 2 imply my desired $n$-dimensional generalization of Eq. 1?


Is there a difference between your $\diamond$ operator and considering $Z:= f(X,Y)$ for any continuous $f$?

@Aruralreader no, with the caveat I'm mainly interested in the case $f: \mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, though presented things in terms of $f: \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ for simplicity (and because this is the case one often sees described).

Answering my question as I can now prove Eq. 1 in a way that easily extends to the $n$-dimensional case. I would still be interested in any references to Eq. 2.
One can compute that for any measurable set $A$ that
$$
\mu(Z_\diamond\in A) = \mu((X,Y)\in \diamond^{-1}(A)) = \int_{\diamond^{-1}(A)} p_{(X,Y)}(x,y)\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y.
$$
Note that $\diamond^{-1}(A) = \bigsqcup_{a\in A}\diamond^{-1}(a)$ holds for any function $\diamond$.
We therefore get that
$$
\mu(Z_\diamond\in A) = \int_{a\in A}\overbrace{\left(\int_{\diamond^{-1}(a)}p_{(X,Y)}(x,y)\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\right)}^{p(a)}\mathrm{d}a.
$$
It follows that $p(a)$ is the density of $Z_\diamond$, as desired.
